# How do I fix postgresql version erros of aws elastick beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, postgresql-9.6, ebcli

I deploy Django project.
and I Use to Django, eb( eb cli ), docker, nginx.

[image]
but, An postgresql version error occurs.

How do I fix postgresql version erros of aws elastick beanstalk?

please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

김용연,

Can you try adding a `.ebextensions` file in your source code with the following contents:

```
option_settings:
  aws:rds:dbinstance
    DBEngineVersion: 9.6.6
```

and then do an `eb deploy`?